# Проблема с Fuel

Tags: kotlin

Раньше, этот код работал, а теперь выдает ошибку типа: "failure android.os.networkonmainthreadexception com.github.kittinunf.fuel.core.FuelError $Companion.wrap(FuelError.kt:85)" ... ну и так далее. С чем это может быть связано? В манифесте тоже прописал доступ к интернету. 
на англ. сайтах вроде было решение, но я в англ. не очень, а через переводчики что-то понять сами знаете...

```
package com.example.indx

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import com.github.kittinunf.fuel.Fuel
import com.github.kittinunf.fuel.core.Headers
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val bodyJson = """{"ApiContext":{"Login":"xxx","Wmid":"123456789","Culture":"ru-RU","Signature":"gdfgkgjdfkgjdfkgdfjkgdfjk="}}"""
        val (requested, responsed, resulted) = Fuel.post("https://api.indx.ru/api/v2/trade/Tools")
            .body(bodyJson)
            .header(Headers.CONTENT_TYPE, "text/json")
            .header(Headers.USER_AGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.90 Safari/537.36")
            .responseString()
        yaz.append(resulted.toString())
    }
}
```

Comment: `networkonmainthreadexception` говорит о том, что вы делаете запрос в сеть в главном потоке, чего делать в андройд нельзя

Comment: значит мне отдельную функцию сделать и через нее вызывать? я не очень шарю в этом пока еще, поэтому не понимаю...

Comment: Тут все возможные варианты правильного использования набросаны. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/how-to-fix-android-os-networkonmainthreadexception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Исключение NetworkOnMainThreadException вас явно указывает на вашу ошибку. Вы пытаетесь сделать сетевой запрос на основном (UI) потоке, что запрещено в Android.

Вам необходимо ваш запрос вынести в отдельный поток.